# Game dedicated server application crash/lag after some time on Ubuntu 18.04 - xfce4 GUI

Tags: networking, process, performance, crash

I've been running a game server application which, after some time (hours of running even full without any kind of problem), crashes with all the people connected to it (it just lags for one/two minutes making most people disconnect although the application stays open, recovering itself for new people connections thereafter).

The server is running on a VPS with one vCore, 500 MB RAM and 400 mbps network bandwidth. I've monitored the resources, and when game server is full, CPU is working at 50%, while the RAM always at about 30%. Upload consuming about 10 mbps.
Firewall disabled.

It's the Assetto Corsa dedicated server which I'm talking about.

Here there are the logs at the moment of crash.

```
2021-05-20 20:42:34,760: PAGE: /cq/kehulistajax.php
2021-05-20 20:42:35,131: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,132: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:35,331: PAGE: /check.php
2021-05-20 20:42:35,608: PAGE: /api/wallet/redDetail
2021-05-20 20:42:35,632: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,632: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:35,655: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:35,734: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:35,891: PAGE: /h5/
2021-05-20 20:42:35,939: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,939: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:35,983: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:35,983: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:36,094: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:36,175: PAGE: /index.php/Wap/Api/getBanner
2021-05-20 20:42:36,269: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:36,269: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:36,450: PAGE: /index.php/Wap/Api/getSystemNotice
2021-05-20 20:42:36,830: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:37,344: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:37,617: PAGE: /script/public.js
2021-05-20 20:42:37,775: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:38,157: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:38,157: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:38,559: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:40,130: PAGE: /api/site/getInfo.do
2021-05-20 20:42:40,214: New connection from &{{14664763300}}
2021-05-20 20:42:40,214: SOCKET NO DELAY SET
2021-05-20 20:42:40,215: PAGE: /locale/Goex/zh/common.js
2021-05-20 20:42:40,219: PAGE: /JS/loginstatus.js
2021-05-20 20:42:40,465: PAGE: /base/goexjs
2021-05-20 20:42:40,622: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:40,834: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:40,918: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:41,171: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:41,171: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:41,178: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:41,178: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:41,359: PAGE: /other/codepay/js/codepay_util.js
2021-05-20 20:42:41,429: PAGE: /anquan/qgga.asp
2021-05-20 20:42:41,679: PAGE: /statics/js/API.js
2021-05-20 20:42:41,796: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:41,797: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:41,930: PAGE: /common/download.js
2021-05-20 20:42:42,712: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:43,977: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:43,988: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:44,353: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:44,857: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:44,868: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:44,868: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:44,970: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:45,186: PAGE: /config
2021-05-20 20:42:45,376: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:45,376: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:45,822: PAGE: /user/login
2021-05-20 20:42:46,100: PAGE: /zz2/address.php
2021-05-20 20:42:46,722: PAGE: /
2021-05-20 20:42:47,831: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:47,832: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:48,667: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:48,696: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,017: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,191: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:51,192: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:51,438: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,641: PAGE: /style.css
2021-05-20 20:42:51,994: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-20 20:42:51,994: PAGE: /js/json.js
2021-05-20 20:42:52,096: PAGE: /api/currency/quotation_new
2021-05-20 20:42:52,174: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:52,174: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:52,178: PAGE: /INFO
2021-05-20 20:42:52,178: REQ
2021-05-20 20:42:52,241: PAGE: /Content/css/wzwstylel.css
2021-05-20 20:42:52,279: EOF
2021-05-20 20:42:52,562: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
- - - - - - -  other example of crash logs - - - - - - - -
2021-05-10 14:47:38,480: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-10 14:47:38,657: PAGE: /JSON|765xxx
2021-05-10 14:47:38,827: ERROR on SendTCPPacket: write tcp ipxxx:9722->ipxxx:43602: write: connection timed out
2021-05-10 14:47:38,827: ERROR on SendTCPPacket: write tcp ipxxx:9722->ipxxx:56621: write: broken pipe
2021-05-10 14:47:38,827: ERROR on SendTCPPacket: write tcp ipxxx:9722->ipxxx:63440: write: broken pipe

many many more for 1/2 minutes

EDIT: I've seen also a no route to host error added to connection timeout and broken pipe.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure what the issue might be but did you check your `dmesg`? You may have a firewall rule limiting the amount of connections or they may be limited by your provider. Also please be careful when posting ip addresses and also please format logs/code as readable as possible (as a code block).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to be the clearest possible, although I'm new here and I'm not an expert of Linux.
Regarding "dmesg" could you explain in detail what should I do?
I'm not aware of any firewall rule limiting the connections, just opened the ports. I've set  big ulimit values for open files because I was getting too many open files error (now solved)

Comment: Just running the command `dmesg` as root will output the kernel messages which might contain some info as to what happens to the packets. While you're at it, could you try running `ulimit -n` to verify the file descriptor limit?

Comment: Also see this answer to tweak some connection parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923785/2519977

Comment: It outputs 1024 "ulimit -n". I've changed the limits through this command "prlimit --pid 12345 --nofile=999999:999999", checked actual open files descriptors of the process with a specific command, was more than 1024 and still no crash with related error. Seems like it's fixed for this reason.

Comment: Oh that should work, but if the pid chanegs or you reboot the server or it's multithreaded etc the limit will still apply. (In other words youll have to rerun prlimit every time).

Comment: The command `sysctl -w fs.file-max=999999` should permanently and globally allow more file descriptors.

Comment: Done the sysctl command already. I've executed the prlimit command to solve the issue fast, in case I'll ever reboot process/system I'll execute it again or make it definitive.
Regarding dmesg here is something that concerned me out:
[125480.179988] systemd-journald[366]: /var/log/journal/cc57de6256064fe58df00ba1beca43a3/system.journal: Journal file has been deleted, rotating.
[125480.183923] systemd-journald[366]: Failed to create new system journal: No such file or directory
[169688.465688] TCP: request_sock_TCP: Possible SYN flooding on port 3389. Sending cookies.  Check SNMP counters

Comment: Hmm `3389` could be rdp. Are you running a remote desktop server on the machine as well? It would be a seperate (security) issue, but you should restrict access by using firewall rules and limit the exposure of services to the internet (the same goes for ssh, telnet and others).

Comment: If you want to find out what program is listening on `3389`, run `netstat -tulpen | grep 3389`.

Comment: Regarding `journald`, this would mean that system/service logs can't be saved in the designated location for some reason.

Comment: Yes I use windows rdp with this port open. I just close the rdp window when I've finished with the server without logging out (as there is server app in process).
For journald I've cleared the logs some day ago without deleting the folder itself if it can help

Comment: I see - I just meant that it's a security issue and the warning may be a result of someone unauthorized trying to connect via rdp or mess with it in another way, shape or form. I'd recommend only using it behind a shh tunnel or vpn or similar: https://superuser.com/questions/1381315/expose-remote-desktop-directly-to-the-internet

Comment: I think I had the same `journald` issue on a server recently: `mkdir /var/log/journal` should fix it (the warning is probably because you dont have a folder called `/var/log/journal` atm). `systemctl restart systemd-journald`  should get `journald` logging to disk again.

Comment: I've checked the folder and journald logs regularly. I think it's not an issue, these errors should be about the last days of clearings. Executed the command to be sure

Comment: Can you give more details on what server client you're using? As in, for what/which game, etc. Certain server client like for T2F and other games had problem like those in the past when people hosted their own instance...

Comment: Assetto Corsa Dedicated Server. I've update the post above, with some questions

Comment: Today have had another crash where suddenly all players are disconnected for 1 minute and then reconnected automatically if they stayed. What could I do? Is there something with DDos filters of the provider? I really don't know anymore what is left to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I've changed provider, but the crash just happened after two days in respect to the older provider that made server last for just 1 day or less.

There isn't still a solution for this issue.